# vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "add" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
    enter code here
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <button @click="add"></button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return{
    methods:{
      add:function(){
        alert("hello");
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

New to vue , having trouble with methods/functions .This is in a basic App.vue component , what i'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods don't belong in the `data` property:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <button @click="add"></button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return{}
  },
  methods:{
    add: function() {
      alert("hello");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer ;). Glad I could help @RoamingStatus